# PHP Carbon / Laravel Eloquent - Check if DateTime value is for the current day

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I am working on a booking system and need to select only the records where a certain field is for today. Not today and in the future, but only today.

The query currently is:

```
$advancedBookings = Booking::where('type', 2)
    ->whereNull('estimated_booking_time')
    ->where('requested_booking_time', ?????);

$advancedBookings->get();
```

The requested_booking_time is the field that I wish to be checked, the date stored is in this format:

```
2017-08-23 08:00:00
```

So I want to only select rows that are on the same day as the current day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand, you want that records which is created today; then just get the today's date.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
```

now your query is like this.

```
$advancedBookings = Booking::where('type', 2)
    ->whereNull('estimated_booking_time')
    ->where('requested_booking_time', $today)->get();
```

Comment: @Lovelock Also consider TZ differences if important.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$advancedBookings = Booking::where('type', 2)
    ->whereNull('estimated_booking_time')
    ->whereDate('requested_booking_time', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereDate` and format your dates with `Carbon`:

```
$advancedBookings = Booking::where('type', 2)
    ->whereNull('estimated_booking_time')
    ->whereDate('requested_booking_time', '=' , Carbon::today()->toDateString());

$advancedBookings->get();
```

Or format the your date before the query with `Carbon`.